# Dynamic Range Based on columns and rows from referenced cells excel/vba

Tags: excel, vba, function, dynamic, range

Let's assume that we want to use a worksheet function such as the countif.
The syntax for such function is countif(Range, Criteria), for instance countif(A2:A10,"Blue").

Now, what I need is to create a dynamic range function in VBA to be used instead of the absolute range A2:A10.
In this dynamic range, the A2 is to be substituted by the column and row correspondent to the location of a cell reference (to be choose by us), and A10 is to be substituted by the column and row of another cell reference.

So, the function which I will call rangesdynamic should have the following syntax: rangesdynamic (cellreference1, cellreference2) and this result is a range that will be used in the syntax of the countif function.

Therefore the final output is supposed to be countif( rangesdynamic, criteria)

Can someone create the VBA code for this function?

Comment: Use `Cells`....?

Comment: `Range("A2:A10")` = `Range("A2", "A10")` = `Range(Range("A2"), Range("A10"))` already do what your `rangesdynamic` function is supposed to do. If you mean to do *countif( rangesdynamic, criteria)*, then you'll have to hard-code the cell ranges into the function. So what's the catch? Please, elaborate.

Comment: Where's the question?  I can see a statement... "I need is to create a dynamic range function in VBA", but you don't seem to have run into any problems yet as you haven't mentioned any.